# Integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was trying to code for the image recognition to train the system for different images of animals and this is the code.I am using anaconda as the interpreter and 
using pycharm for the environment.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os, sys
from PIL import Image

image_path = 'test_images/leopard2.jpg'

size = (299, 299)

infile = image_path
outfile = os.path.splitext(infile)[0] + '_resized.jpg'
try:
  im = Image.open(infile)
  im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
  old_im_size = im.size

## By default, black colour would be used as the background for padding!
new_im = Image.new("RGB", size)

new_im.paste(im,(int(size[0]-old_im_size[0])/2,int(size[1]- 
old_im_size[1])/2))

new_im.save(outfile, "JPEG")
except IOError:
print("Cannot resize '%s'") %infile



# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(outfile, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                in tf.gfile.GFile("output_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
   graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
   graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  _  = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

init_ops = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init_ops)
# Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

 for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
    score = predictions[0][node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
 os.remove(outfile)
```

The error that comes is

```
C:\Users\snklp\Anaconda3\envs\untitled\python.exe 
C:/Users/snklp/Downloads/Transfer-Learning-for-Animal-Classification-in- 
Tensorflow-master/Transfer-Learning-for-Animal-Classification-in-Tensorflow- 
master/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/snklp/Downloads/Transfer-Learning-for-Animal-Classification- 
in-Tensorflow-master/Transfer-Learning-for-Animal-Classification-in- 
Tensorflow-master/test.py", line 19, in <module>
new_im.paste(im,(int(size[0]-old_im_size[0])/2,int(size[1]- 
old_im_size[1])/2))
File "C:\Users\snklp\Anaconda3\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", 
line 1423, in paste
self.im.paste(im, box)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The images i am using is in jpeg format and its in the correct path that was defined in the code.Does anyone knows whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your division by 2 is not wrapped by the int() all. If your `(size[0]-old_im_size[0])` or `(size[1]- old_im_size[1])` comes out odd, the code will break.

Try this :

```
new_im.paste(im,(int((size[0]-old_im_size[0])/2), int((size[1]- old_im_size[1])/2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use int() wrapping around the float object that you are getting or you can use `//` instead of `/` for division. See this:-

```
>>> t = 44/2
>>> t
22.0
>>> int(t)
22
>>> t = 44//2
>>> t
22
```